# Difference between EC-3 with channel map and DD+JOC Atmos?

Tags: encoding, dolby, atmos

I've been playing with EC-3 encoder, trying to get "Dolby Atmos" audio code stream.

My EC-3 code stream consist of 1 independent stream of 5 full-bandwith channels, and 1 dependent stream with Vhl/Vhr+Lts/Rts channels. When I submit my work to my distributor, they say it's not valid "Dolby Atmos".

What are the key differences that set actual Dolby Atmos streams apart from EC-3 streams with channel maps?

Comment: EC-3 and Atmos are both Dolby audio encoding technologies but that’s where the similarities end. You will not be able to encode Atmos with an EC-3 encoder any more than you could make a CD using a tape deck. They are two different technologies and you’ll need an Atmos encoder to make an Atmos file.